# Saber qual o raio do círculo utilizando a biblioteca cv2 em python

Tags: python, opencv, processamento-de-imagens

Preciso encontrar o raio do círculo utilizando a biblioteca cv2, tenho o seguinte codigo:

o que ele faz é circular onde ele encontrar circulos dentro dos parametros que eu defini, agora quero  saber o raio de cada circulo, como posso fazer? não encontrei absolutamente NADA na documentação do opencv sobre isso

````
import scipy.ndimage
import skimage.io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
import math

img = cv2.imread('/content/image.tif',0)

# Set up the SimpleBlobdetector with default parameters.
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

# Define thresholds
#Can define thresholdStep. See documentation. 
params.minThreshold = 0
params.maxThreshold = 255

# Filter by Area.
params.filterByArea = True
params.minArea = 1
params.maxArea = 10000

# Filter by Color (black=0)
params.filterByColor = False  #Set true for cast_iron as we'll be detecting black regions
params.blobColor = 0


# Filter by InertiaRatio (define a precisao que irá circular o circulo)
params.filterByInertia = True
params.minInertiaRatio = 0
params.maxInertiaRatio = 1

# Distance Between Blobs
params.minDistBetweenBlobs = 0

# Setup the detector with parameters
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

# Detect blobs
keypoints = detector.detect(img)

print("Number of blobs detected are : ", len(keypoints))

# Draw blobs
img_with_blobs = cv2.drawKeypoints(img, keypoints, np.array([]), (255,0,0), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

cv2_imshow(img_with_blobs)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()```
````

Comment: [Isso pode ajudar](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/28/measuring-size-of-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/)

Comment: código muito confuso esse aí...